# Rails 3: validates :presence => true vs validates_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between `validates :presence` and `validates_presence_of`? Looking through `ActiveModel` it looks like they setup the validation the same way. However, given the following model definition:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owner_permission, :class_name => 'AccountPermission', :conditions => { :owner => true, :admin => true }
  has_one :owner, :class_name => 'User', :through => :owner_permission, :source => :user

  validate :owner, :presence => true
  validates_associated :owner
end
```

Calling save on an instance of `Account` does not validate the presence of owner. Though, if I use `validates_presence_of` it will.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All those `validates_whatever_of :attr` macros do is call `validates :attr, :whatever => true`.

**The problem is you are using [`validate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate) and not [`validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates).**

Comment: Thanks. I feel really dumb now.

Comment: But why in books like `Agile Web Development with Rails` there's no mention to `validates_whatever_of` way of validating, all validation examples are done using `validates :attr, :whatever => true` ?

Comment: @Ans validates is considered to be the current syntax for Rails 3.x, validates_something_of belongs to the Rails 2.x era

Comment: These methods are not macros in any sense of the word. At least as of Rails 4.1. They are standalone functions that run, not walk, to the correct `Validator` class. `validates :attr` actually has to do a lot of work parsing your arguments to figure out which `Validator` you want.

Comment: @mlibby could you elaborate on this, perhaps provide some reference to documentation that confirms this? This would imply that the `validates_presence_of` mechanism is more efficient. If this is the case then I wonder why the Rails 3/4 way is to use `validates presence :true` ?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb shows the code for `validates_presence_of` and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb shows `validates`. In the latter case lines 113 - 119 are extra work that calling the validators directly would avoid. In terms of efficiency, it only affects application load time (when ActiveRecord files are eval'ed), not the run time itself.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb now, too. How is it that `validate` can accept a `presence: true` option and not throw an exception. Would help us simple ones out...

Answer (score 27):

In Rails 3.x and 4.x - it is now encouraged to use the following syntax:

```
validates :email, presence: true
validates :password, presence: true
```

Instead of the 2.x way:

```
validates_presence_of :email
validates_presence_of :password
```

Comment: Noteworthy to point out (as @mlibby did above) that the Rails2 `validates_*` are more efficient because they call `validates_with` with the appropriate validator right away instead of parsing the arguments and trying different validators. Compare [the Rails2 way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb#L34-L36) with [the Rails3+ way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb#L104-L125).

Answer (score 2):

In fact validates and validates_presence_of is not entirely equal !

validates_presence_of is allowing you to also lazily check by example of the value in the field is included in another table.

Like that:

```
validates_presence_of :pay_type, :inclusion => PaymentType.names
```

Which is something you can't do as easily with something like that

```
validates :pay_type, presence, :inclusion => PaymentType.names
```

Cause the inclusion is only evaluated the first time (not in a lazy way)

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that it is appropriate to use `validates :foo presence: true` when you want to include other validations of `:foo` such as length or uniqueness. But if you know the only validation you'll need for an attribute is presence, then `validates_presence_of` appears to be more efficient.

So:

```
validates :foo, length: {maximum: 50}, uniqueness: true, 
                format: {with: /bar/}, 
                presence: true # lots of validations needed
```

But:

```
validates_presence_of :foo # only presence validation needed
```