# Activerecord uniqueness validation ruby on rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I just started trying my hands on Ruby on rails . i have created a mode states and want that every state name must remain unique so i used

```
uniqueness: true
```

as per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html .
As the above document says that the validation is invoked automatically when object.save is called. but When i try to save the objects with same state_name value , no exception is thrown and the record is saved. Can one please help where i am doing it wrong.

**Model code**

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  validates_presence_of :state_name ,uniqueness: true
end
```

Controller code

```
def create
 @stateName = params[:stateName];
 @state = State.new();
 @state.state_name=@stateName;
 if(@state.save())
   resp = { :message => "success" }
 else
   resp = { :message => "fail" }
 end

 respond_to do |format|
   format.json  { render :json => resp } 
 end
end
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want uniqueness check, change

```
validates_presence_of :state_name ,uniqueness: true
```

to

```
validates :state_name, uniqueness: true
```

If you want uniqueness and presence check both, use

```
validates :state_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
```

An alternate syntax is shown below, however, [syntax shown above should be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14217163/794242)

```
validates_uniqueness_of :fname
validates_presence_of :fname
```

Also, as per [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness), please note following with respect to usage of `uniqueness: true`

> It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may
>   happen that two different database connections create two records with
>   the same value for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid
>   that, you must create a unique index on both columns in your database.
>
> The validation happens by performing an SQL query into the model's
>   table, searching for an existing record with the same value in that
>   attribute.

What this means is that it is possible that if multiple users are trying to save records concurrently, there is a possibility records with duplicate `state_name` can get created as each `save` is happening on different thread

Comment: Okay... thanks for helping.If i have to create a unique constraint in the database to ensure uniqueness , why even i bother validating uniqueness via model... db wont let duplicate entry come in anyhow !!!